# Непрерывное построение виджета при передаче аргументов через Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

Это код с таблицей:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class ShowTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowTableState createState() => _ShowTableState();
}

class _ShowTableState extends State<ShowTable> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];

  void _load() async {
    // String linkOfDict = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    String linkOfDict =
        '/data/data/com.example.eng_translator/app_flutter/sales.csv';

    String contents = await File(linkOfDict).readAsString();
    data = CsvToListConverter().convert(contents);

    setState(() {});

    print(data);
  }

  @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // _load();  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
              return Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    row.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Передача ргумента:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/show_table', arguments: linkOfDict);
```

Когда жестко прописана переменная **linkOfDict**, то таблица появляется без проблем и print (который *print(data);*) прописывается один раз в консоли, как и положено. С этим вариантом все в порядке. Но если я задаю **linkOfDict** не жестко, а получаю через **ModalRoute** (закоментировано в коде), то получаю следующие ошибки:

*E/flutter ( 4289): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _ShowTableState.initState() completed.
E/flutter ( 4289): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
E/flutter ( 4289): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.*

Когда метод **_load()** используется в **build(BuildContext context)**, а не в **initState()**, то таблица рисуется, но вот **print(data)** обновляется с большой скоростью. И не имеет значения, **linkOfDict** прописан жестко или принимается через **ModalRoute**

Answer (score 0):

Вижу тут две сложности -- как получить доступ к аргументам внутри контекста и как перестроить интерфейс после загрузки данных.

Ввиду особенностей работы Flutter, Вы не можете получить аргументы из `ModalRoute.of(context)` в `initState`. Только в `build()` или `didChangeDependencies()`.

Использование `build()` в Вашем случае можно исключить сразу, т.к `build()` может вызываться сколько угодно раз(поэтому у вас вызывалось большое количество принтов) и это по большому счёту должна быть чистая функция

Можно получить аргументы в `didChangeDependencies()`, но, возможно Вам понравится вариант передачи пути к словарю из родительского виджета:

```dart
class TablePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static final route = '/show_table';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dictPath = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(body: ShowTable(dictPath));
  }
}
```

Вторая проблема: перестроение интерфейса после загрузки данных.
Ваш вариант с пустым `setState()` внутри `_load()` действительно сработает, но возможно удобнее будет использовать виджет FutureBuilder:

```dart
class ShowTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final dictPath;

  ShowTable(this.dictPath);

  @override
  _ShowTableState createState() => _ShowTableState();
}

class _ShowTableState extends State<ShowTable> {
  Future<List<List<dynamic>>> _load() async {
    String contents = await rootBundle.loadString(widget.dictPath);
    final dataList = CsvToListConverter().convert(contents);

    print(dataList);

    return dataList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Table")),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _load(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<List<List<dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Table(
                  columnWidths: {0: FlexColumnWidth(1)},
                  border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
                  children: snapshot.data.map((item) {
                    return TableRow(
                      children: item.map((row) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              row.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Решил вопрос, использованием FutureBuilder.
Благодарю.